# Can't select release variant

Tags: android, android-studio

I new to android dev. I made an app with external native lib (openCV), I'm trying to change the build variant from debug to release. It works for the native lib (I can choose from debug to release and it seems ok). However I can't pass the app from debug to release : in the build variant, if I check the release mode it automatically switch back to debug.

Any advice ?

EDIT : the build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'key0'
            keyPassword '-----'
            storeFile file('----')
            storePassword '----'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "-----"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions"
                abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'mips', 'mips64'
                /* arguments "-DANDROID_STL=c++_static" */
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary320')
}
```

Note: I replaced some confidential values with ----

Comment: Did you have a 'release' build variant defined? Can you edit your post and add you app's build.gradle config?

Comment: Yes, it appears in the module configuration, and also defined in the build.gradle

Comment: Weird uh? If you run assembleDebug or assembleRelease from command line or from "Gradle projects" -> Build, all goes ok? If it is so, I blame your local Android Studio install, because your Gradle DSL look fine.

Comment: It works in command line, I reinstall AS but without success (it was a fresh install also). I managed to set debug/release modifying by hand the app.iml (changing debug to release), now I can change debug/release in the build variant selector ... Strange issue.

Comment: @rperrot's tip worked for me. I think you should submit it as an answer. I was having the same problem (suddenly appeared for no apparent reason), and it even persisted through an update from AS 2.x to 3.0 (I'd been postponing updating and figured it might fix the problem but it didn't). After editing the app.iml file and reopening, I can now toggle it in AS as usual. Thanks!

Comment: deleting the .idea folder and open the project up again worked for me